# Reading file using variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables

I am working on a batch based program and I really can't get arround this:
I want to test and read for a file using variable. This is what came in my mind but it does not work:

```
set /p target=Input:
if exist %target% (
    more %target%.txt
) else (
    echo File does not exist!
)
```

Comment: `it does not work` doesn't explain what your problem is, can you please expand…

Comment: shouldn't you use the same file name with `if exist ...` and `more ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that :

```
@echo off
set /p src=Enter file name:

IF exist %src% (
   more "%src%" 
   ) ELSE ( echo File does not exists )
```

Result is:

```
Z:\>test.bat
Enter file name:src.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc

Z:\>
```

or

```
Z:\>test.bat
Enter file name:wrong.txt
File does not exists

Z:\>
```

With bat file test.bat and test file src.txt containing the following text:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Comment: Thank you!I really didn't thought putting those...A.K.A "%src%"